# Подключение IP камеры в локальную сеть через 2 роутера

Tags: ip, камера

Всем привет, извиняюсь если вопрос не по теме сайта, но пока не нашел куда еще отписать.

Есть 2 роутера, №1 и №2.
К роутеру №1 подключен главный интернет кабель, к этому же роутеру подключен видеорегистратор.

С роутера №1(Lan3 порт) к роутеру №2 (WAN Port) подключил кабель, все работает.
Но к роутеру №2 - по LAN подключена IP камера, и получается так, что у роутера №2 своя локальная сеть, которую не видит регистратор который подключен к роутеру №1.

Как правильно подключить так, чтобы IP камера подключена была к роутеру №2, но регистратор видел её в общей локальной сети?...

Пробовал так:

От роутера №1(Lan3) к роутеру №2(Lan1) подключал кабель, тогда роутер №2 работает как свич, и IP камеру видно в сети, но в таком случае роутер№2 не выдаёт вайфай сеть, так как работает как свич...

Вижу вариант поставить еще 1 свич, в который будет подключаться IP камера, и от свича будет идти кабель на роутер №2 (WAN).

Спасибо за ответы, гуглю, но вариантов не нашел конкретных

Comment: Попробуйте во 2ом роутере отключить встроенный DHCP сервер, а вместо него использовать 1ый роутер

Comment: Выполните настройку роутера 2 с пробросом необходимых портов на камеру (port mapping). Видеорегистратором подключайтесь по адресу WAN-порта второго роутера. Либо просто вынесите на роутере 2 камеру в DMZ.

Comment: @Akina у меня не статический ип

Comment: WAN внутреннего (второго) роутера для решения поставленной задачи ОБЯЗАН иметь статический адрес из подсети LAN первого роутера. За пределами DHCP-скопа, либо зарезервированный.

Comment: @Akina я каждое Ваше слово гуглю, я не особо разбираюсь в сетевых делах, можно попроще?)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос: модели обоих роутеров (по отдельности), текущие настройки первого роутера (внешний адрес, внутренний адрес, настройки DHCP-сервера; внешний адрес и его шлюз можно, если боитесь, заменить на 100.100.100.xxx), настройки второго роутера, адреса видеорегистратора и IP-камеры.